# Remove changes from Child Branch PR by updating Parent branch

Tags: git, git-branch, pull-request

I've a situation like ,
I've created a branch B from a Branch A , changed few things and raise a Pull Request .
Later come to know that those changes should be the part of Branch A and not Branch B ,
and should not come in PR of Branch B ,
So if i update the parent branch Branch A( add those changes there), and pull the changes to Branch B , so now does the PR of branch B will show those changes that i added earlier or those will be gone

Answer (score 0):

You can try fast-forwarding from B to A:

```
git checkout A
git merge --ff-only B
```

which will apply the commits to A as they are in B or fail if there's any conflict.

Afterwards you can simply `git reset --hard <commit>` the B branch if you want to change it, or re-create B branch from A once again, so it's 1:1.

Or, you can use [cherry picking](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick), apply only the commits you want and then reset the B branch to commit you desire.

Regarding the behavior in a pull request, the B branch will still contain the commits, but the git UI (e.g. Gitea) will probably not show them as the common commits would then match.

Alternatively rebase the branch and remove the common commits e.g. with:

```
git checkout B
git rebase A
git push --force  # to update the PR
```

Comment: yeah that will work for merging , but my requirement here is like those changes should not come in the Pull Request that i raised on Branch B . somehow it should be gone from there , and i can't delete it .. i need it .. but should not come as new change on that PR